# Минимизация функционала в R

Tags: r

Добрый день, я пытаюсь минимизировать следующую функцию:

```
solution<-function(bet1,bet2,bet3,lyam)паа
{ 
  SecondPart<-as.data.frame(data=0,nrow(payments), ncol(payments))
  for(i in 1:nrow(payments))
    for(j in 1:ncol(payments)){
      SecondPart[i,j]<-bet2*lyam*(1-EXPONENT[i,j])/payments[i,j]
 }
  ThirdPart<-bet3*(SecondPart/bet2-EXPONENT)
  Nelson<-bet1+SecondPart+ThirdPart
  Nelson<-replace(Nelson, is.na(Nelson), 0)
  theor.price<-as.matrix(t(Nelson))%*%as.matrix(coupon)
  theor.price<-diag(theor.price)
  RSS<-(price-theor.price)^2
  RSS
}
trial<-optim(par(0,0,0,0), fn=solution, gr=NULL, method=c("BFGS"), lower= -Inf, upper=Inf, control=list())
```

Выходит следующая ошибка:

```
Error in optim(par(0, 0, 0, 0), fn = solution, gr = NULL, method = c("BFGS"),  :
 (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double
```

В качестве исходных данных используются матрицы (10х6) с форматом данных num. Если задавать значения параметров отдельно, то функция считает все правильно, ошибок не выдается.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум надо исправить ошибки явные, вызов корректный optim() будет выглядеть вот так:
    trial<-optim(c(0,0,0,0), fn=solution, gr=NULL, method="BFGS", lower= -Inf, upper=Inf)

К сожалению Вы не приложили минимальное содержимое payments для дальнейшей помощи в отладке кода.